# Angular 4 primEng checkbox error

Tags: angular, primeng

Do you know this issue? When I am trying to check a checkbox, error occurs:

```
Checkbox.html:7 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
at Checkbox.addValue (checkbox.ts:106)
at Checkbox.updateModel (checkbox.ts:76)
at Checkbox.onClick (checkbox.ts:66)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (Checkbox.html:7)
at handleEvent (view.ts:140)
at callWithDebugContext (services.ts:645)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (services.ts:241)
at dispatchEvent (util.ts:173)
at eval (element.ts:221)
at HTMLDivElement.eval (dom_renderer.ts:75)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js@0.8.4?main=browser:398)
at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:253)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js@0.8.4?main=browser:397)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js@0.8.4?main=browser:165)
at HTMLDivElement.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js@0.8.4?main=browser:460)
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/PPIk2sjGNI9EyGhdkA9e?p=preview

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying `binary` option:

```
<p-checkbox binary="true" (onChange)="onCheckboxSelected(node)"></p-checkbox>
```

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mts9CG8Syc9KmQfFurx1?p=preview)**

> binary    Default 'false' Allows to select a boolean value instead of
>   multiple values.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox